# Any alternative for IsSubclassOf or IsAssignableFrom in C# Metro-style

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Is there any alternative for `IsSubclassOf` or `IsAssignableFrom` in C# Metro-style?

I'm trying to make this code run on Metro but can't find alternative.

```
if ((ui.GetType() == type) || (ui.GetType().IsSubclassOf(type)))
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 55):

Many of the reflection methods can be found in the `System.Reflection.TypeInfo` class.

You can get an instance of `TypeInfo` for your `Type` using the `GetTypeInfo` extension method, provided by `System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions`:

```
using System.Reflection;

// ...

ui.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(type)
```

Comment: Many of reflection methods are not available in metro-style windows 8 .net framework. This is the reason that I was looking for alternative. but I think there is no alternative so seems like have to use "is" or "as" with explicit type.

Comment: @MichaelSync:  I don't understand why you say there is no alternative.  Does `TypeInfo` not work for you?  If not, why not?

Comment: Please take a look at metro .net reference. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441595(v=vs.110).aspx .. a lot of types are missing there..

Comment: What, exactly, are you looking for?  If you don't state what you need to do, I can't help.  Your original question was whether there was an alternative for `IsSubclassOf` and `IsAssignableFrom`... the answer to that is yes:  they exist, in `TypeInfo`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use this:

```
using System.Reflection;

// ...

ui.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(type.GetTypeInfo());
```

This works in Metro.